# scala code error converting unixtimestamp to datetime format in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

i am facing issue regarding converting unixtime stamp to datetime format. i have a dataframe having unixtimestamp column i want to convert it to datetime column. i tried using sql also

```
  unixtimestamp is 1531294892700

  spark.sql("select from_unixtime(timestamp,'YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') 
  FROM 
  table1 WHERE id=50
```

on dataframe also m not getting the result just the date only

```
   df4.select(to_date(from_unixtime($"timestamp" / 1000)))
```

it give output like this

```
 50494-10-20 05:55:00    

 output i want is Wednesday, July 11, 2018 7:41:32.700 AM
 or 
 07/11/2018 07:41:32
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems to be stored as millisecond since the epoch. You have divide

```
val df = Seq(1531294892700L).toDF("timestamp")
val seconds = df.withColumn("timestamp", $"timestamp" / 1000)
```

Convert to timestamp

```
val timestamp = seconds.withColumn("timestamp", from_unixtime($"timestamp"))
```

And cast:

```
timestamp.select($"timestamp".cast("date")).show
// +----------+
// | timestamp|
// +----------+
// |2018-07-11|
// +----------+
```

If you want to format use `date_format`, for example

```
timestamp.select(date_format($"timestamp",  "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")).show
// +-------------------------------------------+
// |date_format(timestamp, MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss)|
// +-------------------------------------------+
// |                        07/11/2018 07:41:32|
// +-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: `Seq(1531294892700L).toDF("timestamp")` is wrong, `Seq` is not a `rdd`